# Problemas com a versão do .NET Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, framework, ftp

Eu tenho uma aplicação ASP.Net MVC 5 e WebApi, na versão .NET 4.5.2 e os postar no meu servidor FTP tenho o seguinte erro (imagem no final do post)

E perguntando para o suporte técnico da empresa, eles me responderam o seguinte:

> A partir do .Net Framework 4.0, a Microsoft modificou um componente interno do chamado CAS (Code Access Security), que é quem determina como as classes podem acessar umas às outras.
>
> Para que sua aplicação seja funcional em nossos servidores, será necessário que esteja com os três quesitos abaixo:
>
> Medium trust
>   MVC4
>   Integrated

Eis a pergunta: Há alguma forma de fazer com que o meu projeto atual tenha essas especificações sem ter que criar outro projeto?

Anexo:

[image: Error.png]

Comment: Sua hospedagem é locaweb?

Comment: @LINQ é sim ....

Comment: Você tem duas opções: 1) Trocar de hospedagem; 2) Reescrever a aplicação

Comment: é ... acabei reescrevendo mesmo e funcionou